# Dejar hora marcada en datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy utilizando [DateTimePicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) y me encuentro con un problema.

```
//Seleccion de fecha y hora
    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:true,
        minDate:0,
        inline:true,
        format:'Y-m-d H:i',
        allowTimes:[
         '14:00', '15:00', '18:50'
        ],
        defaultTime:'18:50',
        startDate: manana,
        minDate: manana,
        maxDate: maximo,
        disabledWeekDays: [0, 6],
        value: manana,
        onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
            hayFecha = 1;
            activarBoton();
            $('#fecha_recogida').val($input.val());
            //alert($input.val())
        }
    });
```

Tengo unas horas habilitadas, ya que son las únicas posibles de recogida. Pero no consigo dejar una marcada. He mirado la documentación pero no encuentro nada que me lo haga funcionar: lo que más pensé que funcionaría es esto `defaultTime:'18:50'` pero tampoco funciona.

Alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segun la documentacion puedes agregar la fecha y tiempo de inicio como un valor del input, mira aca:

Si tienes un input en HTML para el datetimepicker:

```html
<input id="datetimepicker1" type="text" style="display: none;">
```

Con este script te debe agregar el tiempo

```javascript
$.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
const d = new Date();
let day = d.getDate();
let month = d.getMonth() + 1;
let year = d.getFullYear();

let date_input = day + '.' + month + '.' + year;
let dtp_time = date_input + ' 18:50';

$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  lang: 'es',
  value: dtp_time,
  allowTimes: [
    '14:00', '15:00', '18:50'
  ],
  inline: true,
  format: 'd.m.Y H:i'
})
```

Si quieres ver el codigo en accion, aqui puedes revisarlo en JSFiddle, como no encontre un CDN, agregue la libreria directamente en el Fiddle para poder ejecutarlo:

https://jsfiddle.net/8zspn026/

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @AugustoM